# How to add DBContext to services from another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, entity-framework-core

on .net core 2.1,
I have loaded the assembly to the application using

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddApplicationPart([Assembly])
```

But the assembly contains its DB context , the problem is that 
I am not able to load the DBContext from the assembly, in a similar way of loading the controllers.
Typically we add the DB Context using

```
services.AddDbContext<[DBCOntextType]>([options]);
```

I cannot get to pass the type to this function (AddDBContext) using reflection as follow :

```
 System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = services.GetType().GetMethod("AddDbContext",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
```

method variable is always null.

Also if the assembly contains a startup.cs file I am not able to run this startup along with the startup of the main app.

Please let me know if there is a solution
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: @thehennyy I have updated the question with the reflection code that does not work

Comment: `AddDbContext` seems to be an extension method, so it is not present in the type of `services` but somewhere else. Most likely the method is defined in `EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions`.

Comment: @thehennyy Thanks yes,  it was the reflection solution that needed to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the reflection solution as @thehenny directed me to the right direction

Here is the code assuming that you already loaded the type dbContextType from assembly

```
var type = typeof (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions);
                System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = type.GetMethods().Where(i=>i.Name  == "AddDbContext" 
                && i.IsGenericMethod==true).FirstOrDefault();

System.Reflection.MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(dbContextType);

Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> action = new Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>(options =>[Your Options]);
object[] parametersArray = new object[] { services, action,null,null };
generic.Invoke(services, parametersArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add extension for service collection to an external project

```
public static IServiceCollection AddModule(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<EventManagementDbContext>(opt =>
            opt.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("Postgresql"), x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__efcore_migrations", ModuleConstants.DefaultDbShema)));

        return services;
    }
```

and then add to your startup

```
builder.Services.AddModule(builder.Configuration);
```